# Open to or open for further discussion?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

This is a bit similar to another question already asked but I think the context is somewhat different.

I was taking a sample Cambridge CPE test and one of the tasks involved was to change a sentence using a given word, changing neither the sentence's meaning nor the word's.

The sentence was:

> The manager refused to discuss his decision further.

The word to use was "open".

> The manager stated that his decision [insert answer here] discussion.

My answer was:

> The manager stated that his decision [was not open **for** further] discussion.

The answer key says [was not open **to** further].

Was my answer also correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct as well. To get a feeling for how often certain phrases are used, you can use the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=open+*+further+discussion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&):

[image]

Of course, this doesn't tell you that the phrases have the same meaning; for that, you can click on the links below the graph which show [a few samples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22open%20for%20further%20discussion%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) where the phrase is used, with the same meaning as your exercise.

[image]